# unable to get parameters from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Unable to get parameters passed from javascript to loginme.php**

This is simple form in 
**index.php**

```
<form method="POST">

            <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid"></input>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Log in" onclick="letUserLogin()"/>
</form>
```

Javascript function :
**myscript.js**

```
function letUserLogin() {
    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      alert(xmlhttp.responseText); //only shows 'and'
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","loginme.php?userid="+userid+"&pass="+pass,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Simple echo statement in loginme.php
**loginme.php**

```
<?php

// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['userid']; 
$password=$_POST['pass']; 

echo"$username and $password";

?>
```

Comment: userid is in the URL which you get using GET. pass is never actually sent.

Comment: You dont seems like passing the password and more over for post you should pass data in the request body not as query string.

Comment: Code Edited. Now password is also sent along with user id.

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: If those asterisks are really in your code, that would cause it to fail.

Comment: Nothing. only shows " and " in alert .

Comment: @sam: edited. asterisks are no in code. it was a comment

Comment: have you tried `alert(userid+' '+pass);` after declaring it? If yes , can you find those values there?

Comment: @Shaunak: yes ,values are correct when displaying in alert() in myscript.js

Comment: try Alvaro's answer.. use $_GET, instead of $_POST.. It may work for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing **GET** parameters:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","loginme.php?userid="+userid+"&pass="+pass,true);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... thus you need to fetch them from `$_GET`, not `$_POST`:

```
$username=$_GET['userid']; 
$password=$_GET['pass'];
```

You possibly want to use the [send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send()) method instead to send your data. Right now, your payload is empty:

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: It worked. But if we are using POST method in open() function , then why using GET in php?

Comment: `$_GET` is the array that contains get parameters. It has nothing to do with the request protocol. You can send both get and post on the same request. Whatever's in the URL itself, is get.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this with JQuery quite easily if you want:
This method also allows you to put the URL within the action parameter of the form and uses POST which is more secured for transferring password information:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('submit', "form", function(e){ //We add a listener
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize())
    .done( function( data ) {
     //Do something with response          
 });
});
```

Note that you can of course change the listener to only listen to a specific form. In this case all forms submits will be caught rather than a specific one in a page.

HTML:

```
<form action="/path/to/loginme.php">
    <input type="text" name="userid">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$username=$_POST['userid']; 
$password=$_POST['pass']; 
echo "$username and $password";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `POST` but explicitly setting the values into the query string, `GET` style. So basically you are sending a blank `POST`.

You need to send the values like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","loginme.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("userid=" + userid + "&pass=" + pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var userid =encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userid").value)
var pass =encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("pass").value)
var parameters="userid="+userid+"&pass="+pass
mypostrequest.open("POST", "loginme.php", true)
mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
mypostrequest.send(parameters)
```

use of `encodeURIComponent()` to encode any special characters within the parameter values.
Call `setRequestHeader()` and set its content type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. This is needed for any POST request made via Ajax.